# how to change the box shadow after click in the input using angular 6?

Tags: html, css, input, angular6, box-shadow

I'm using angular 6 and material in my project and I have an input box. I want the box shadow to change after I click in the input and after I click out, here are my codes :

**.html**

```
<div class="search-bar" fxFlex>
    <form class="search-form" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-xs>
      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
      <input type="text" matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search" autofocus="true" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

**.css**

```
 .search-bar .search-form {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 99.8%;
    border: solid 1px rgba(119, 119, 119, .55);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  }
```

I don't know how can I get the active status of input

Comment: Can you use JS?

Comment: @JBDouble05 no I have to use angular!! I just want to know how to find out that the input is focused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the `:focus` pseudo-class:

```
input:focus form {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}
```

And if it's not focused:

```
input:not(:focus) form {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I think it's ok but how can I change the search-bar box-shadow after focus? in the css the .search-bar .search-form has box-shadow

Comment: Just add your box-shadow to the rules above

Comment: if i use box shadow, it changes the input shadow! i need to change the form shadow!  input:focus {
   .search-bar .search-form
}  does not working

Comment: But `input: focus {.search-bar .search-form}` wouldn't do anything, you need to add those rules into `input: focus`

Comment: i put the box-shadow rule in input but it changes the input box-shadow!! i want to change the form shadow! can you edit your answer? i think i don't understand you well

Comment: Oh, so you want the *form* to have a shadow when the *input* is selected?

Comment: well, nothing changed! I used your first solution!